# How is this pronounced? 使い途

Tags: pronunciation

What is this 使い途? I get tsukaimichi on Google translate,  but on a jisho app, there isn't a translation.

Answer (score 2):

It's read つかいみち as Google says. It means the same thing as 使い道 ("usage", "uses", "ways of using").

This 途 is one of the several ways to write みち in kanji. Although 道 is the normal way to write it, sometimes 径, 途 and 路 are used in novels and other forms of aesthetic writing to add some "flavor".